# What is the meaning of `X{code}` in Drop-wizard log format

Tags: java, logging, dropwizard

Sorry if I am asking very basic question here. But i am using a dropwizard application in which log format is given as `"%-6level [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"`.

And application logs contains below lines :-

```
INFO  [2017-06-07 13:54:43,828] com.foo.Bar: In Get Method
```

I understood that meaning of `%-6level , date and %t and %msg %n` in log format but couldn't get the meaning of **%X{code}** and **%logger{5}** and don't see these printing in my logs.

Can someone point me to a proper doc where each of these parameters of log format is explained in details.

Comment: Which logging framework is used ?

Comment: i am using dropwizard which internally uses `logback`.

Comment: `%X` is for mapped diagnostic contexts (MDCs). `%logger` is the name of the logger. https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

Comment: So when you read the documentation of Logback, it didn't describe those formats? You did **read the documentation**, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice documentation about layouts in logback : [Layouts](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html)

For the `logger{length}` part :

> Outputs the name of the logger at the origin of the logging event.
>   This conversion word takes an integer as its first and only option.
>   The converter's abbreviation algorithm will shorten the logger name,
>   usually without significant loss of meaning. Setting the value of
>   length option to zero constitutes an exception. It will cause the
>   conversion word to return the sub-string right to the rightmost dot
>   character in the logger name. The next table provides examples of the
>   abbreviation algorithm in action.

For the `X{key:-defaultVal}` part :

> Outputs the MDC (mapped diagnostic context) associated with the thread
>   that generated the logging event.

More information about MDC can be found here : [Mapped Diagnostic Context](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)

With your configuration you would call it like e.g :

```
MDC.put("code", "whateverCode");
```

Comment: thanks for the nice explanation , so if i am not wrong `%t` is for printing the thread name whcih is blank in my case and `com.foo.Bar` is the name of the logger which i give while creating my logger object ?

Comment: Yes exactly, note that you may use `%thread` instead of `%t` if you prefer (refer to the above link about layouts) .